# C++ How to get string/char in between 2 words

Tags: c++

i got a word that is

AD#Andorra

Got a few questions:

How do i check
AD?Andorra exist

? is a wildcard, it could be comma or hex or dollar sign or other value

then after confirm AD?Andorra exist, how do i get the value of ?

Thanks,
Chen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem can be solved generally with a regular expression match. However, for the specific problem you presented, this would work:

```
std::string input = getinput();
char at2 = input[2];
input[2] = '#';
if (input == "AD#Andorra") {
    // match, and char of interest is in at2;
} else {
    // doesn't match
}
```

If the `?` is supposed to represent a string also, then you can do something like this:

```
bool find_inbetween (std::string input,
                     std::string &output,
                     const std::string front = "AD",
                     const std::string back = "Andorra") {
    if ((input.size() < front.size() + back.size())
        || (input.compare(0, front.size(), front) != 0)
        || (input.compare(input.size()-back.size(), back.size(), back) != 0)) {
        return false;
    }
    output = input.substr(front.size(), input.size()-front.size()-back.size());
    return true;
}
```

Comment: A nightmare to debug! Please, please don't use one-line if & return.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on C++11/use Boost (which I strongly recommend!) use regular expressions. Once you gain some level of understanding all text processing becomes easy-peasy!

```
#include <regex> // or #include <boost/regex>

//! \return A separating character or 0, if str does not match the pattern
char getSeparator(const char* str)
{
    using namespace std; // change to "boost" if not on C++11
    static const regex re("^AD(.)Andorra$");
    cmatch match;
    if (regex_match(str, match, re))
    {
        return *(match[1].first);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming your character always starts at position 3!
use the string functions `substr`:

```
your_string.substr(your_string,2,1)
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `substr` for checking just one (fixed) position inside a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++11, i recommend you to use regex instead of direct searching in your string.